# How can I declare delegate to a function with default parameters in an interface?

Tags: c#, interface, delegates

I have an `interface` of the following type

```
public interface IMyInterface{
     void Select(Action<int,int> selector)
}
```

Now this `interface` is implemented in many ways where the `selector` delegate parameter in `Select` function may point to a function with a default parameter.
Ex:

```
public class MyClass {
     public void func(int a, int b=1){
         //body of function
     }
}
```

The function call is made from a different class in the following form

```
Select(new MyClass().func(10));
```

But the above code throws an error saying `Delegate System.Action<int,int> does not take one argument`. In order to support `default arguments`, one need to declare a customized delegate. But declaration of a delegate is not allowed in an interface.

So, how do I curb the error in the above scenario?

Comment: Are you shure your `MyClass` is implementation of `IMyInterface`?

Comment: Sorry my mistake...Made the edit!!

Comment: Ok, let's go further. `new MyClass().func(10)` is definitely **not** `Action<int, int>`, it's just a result of execution of func method. `new MyClass().func` **is** `Action<int, int>`. So I don't quite understant the goal of your call to `Select` in the manner you've specified.

Comment: Yes but MyClass.func() has the second parameter as `default parameter`. So I am not passing the second value in function call. How do I make the `Action` delegate accept the second parameter as a default one?

Comment: You are heading the wrong way, the arguments are specified in the Select() method implementation.  Which does something like selector(42, 666);  You'll never get a default value applied, it can't work when the call is made through a delegate.  Default values are applied at the call site, not in the callee.  It compiles when you use `obj.Select(new Action<int, int>((a, b) => new MyClass().func(a)));` but that's almost certainly not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you cant pass `new MyClass().func(10)` as your delegate reference. You can just pass `new MyClass().func`.

The signature of your Select method should be changed to `void Select(Action<int, int?> selector, int a, int b);`. Delegate has nullable parameter so that reference method has option to either send a value or use default value.

I have a working code below try this

```
 public interface IMyInterface
{
    void Select(Action<int, int?> selector, int a, int? b);
}

public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    public void func(int a, int? b=1 )
    {
        //body of function
    }


    public void Select(Action<int, int?> action, int a, int? b)
    {
        action(a, b);
    }       
}


class Program 
{        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass cls = new MyClass();
        cls.Select(cls.func, 10, null);
    }

}
```